# Prevent <div> taking new line; <span> not working

Tags: css, html

I am coding a page with a banner at the top which should contain a series of buttons. The following code works in all but the buttons are taking a new line when they should appear side by side. I know that div automatically takes a new line and that I should use span, but when I do it doesn't stretch the banner to fit the button like it does with a div. I have tried using several variations of float but to no avail.

```
<style type="text/css" media=screen>

body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica, times;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#banner{
  background: url('images/banner_background.png');
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 3;
}

#banner #button {
  padding:10px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  background: url('images/button.png');
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  width:100px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">

    <div id="button">
      dfsdfsfdsdfs
    </div>

    <div id="button">
      sddfdfdsf
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing to do: replace `#button` with `.button`. **Do not** use id's multiple times on a page.

Comment: also id should be unique, use class if you have multiple elements and you want to put specific css to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the padding still work on an inline element like a `span`, you would have to set it to `display: inline-block` - it will still be in the text flow, unlike block elements, but accept width/height, padding and margin the same way an image does. Images are inline-blocks by default.

CSS:

```
#banner .button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
  background: url('images/button.png');
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  width:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="button">
  sddfdfdsf
</span>
<span class="button">
  sddfdfdsf
</span>
```

**Important:** IDs are unique to a single element. If you have multiple buttons, use classes. I adjusted that as well.

Comment: Thanks! Taught me something.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `<div>`-s `inline-block` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNSZL/)

Also ID-s should be unique.

And if you need buttons, then you have to use the `<button>` tag - it just makes more semantic sense. And it can be styled anything you want - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNSZL/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `display: inline` for a `div` rather than using a `span`.

`div` set the `display` to be `block` by default, while `span` to be `inline`. You can't set `padding` or `margin` values to `span` because it is designed to be used in a lighter way (e.g., underline or italic for some words). So it's better to use `div` if you can do so and set attributes like `display: inline` to meet with the special needs.

Comment: There's nothing special about spans that make them unable to have margins applied to them.  Margins are restricted based on the element's display type.  Inline elements like span can't have margins, but if you change the display type... presto!  instant margins.